# alternate between cell.layer.hidden YES/NO when pressing a button, swift

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `button` in `tableview`'s section 1 `footer`. I'm trying to hide the `cells` in that `section` when I press that `button` and unhide them when I press it again.

Currently it works half way, it is hidden when I load the `view`, as expected, and when I press the `button` it shows the `cells` in `section` 1, as expected, but when I press it again nothing happens and the cells stay visible.

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
var isCellHidden = true

func Action(sender: UIButton)
 {
        if isCellHidden
        {
            isCellHidden = false
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            isCellHidden = false
        }

        if !(isCellHidden)
        {
            isCellHidden = true
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            isCellHidden = true    
        }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> TableViewCell {
if indexPath.section == 1
 {
    if isCellHidden
    {
        cell.layer.hidden = true    
    }
 }

 return cell 
 }
```

Comment: You really don't see any warnings when you type `icCellHidden == true` inside the your `if` block ?

Comment: ok, just fixed that, I was too desperate so I was trying every possible combo for the last couple hours. 
I know isCellHidden == true is redundant, I updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: It would be much easier to just invert the value of that variable, rather than check the value and set it to the opposite.. Something like: 

`isCellHidden = !isCellHidden;`
`self.tableView.reloadData();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import UIKit

import QuartzCore

var isCellHidden = true


func Action(sender: UIButton){

    isCellHidden = !isCellHidden
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> TableViewCell {

if indexPath.section == 1
    {
            cell.layer.hidden = isCellHidden
    }

return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> TableViewCell {
// Create a cell here
if indexPath.section == 1 {
    if isCellHidden == true {
        cell.layer.hidden = true    
    } else {
        cell.layer.hidden = false
    }
    return cell
}
```

Because you are reusing your cell and the former state is remembered. That is why you need to set it for each case.

Comment: I tried that too, it doesn't work. and I'm pretty sure when you refresh the tableView the cell layer redraws so it's unnecessary...

Comment: Actually the table view reuses cells if you are using it with dequeue. That is why you should always set properties for each case. Maybe here it won't make a difference since you only have one row, but if you had multiple rows you would have issues when scrolling.

Comment: Maybe the section is 0 and not 1?

Comment: Hm, I do have more cells in that section, but it still doesn't work :(. anything else that i'm doing wrong here? it is definitely section 1, as I'm able to show the cells after they are hidden but not the opposite.